# Create decorator that can see current class method

Tags: python, decorator, class-method

Can you create a decorator inside a class that will see the classes methods and variables?

The decorator here doesnt see: self.longcondition()

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    # decorator that will see the self.longcondition ???
    class canRun(object):
            def __init__(self, f):
                self.f = f

            def __call__(self, *args):
                if self.longcondition(): # <-------- ???
                    self.f(*args)

    # this is supposed to be a very long condition :)
    def longcondition(self):
        return isinstance(self.name, str)

    @canRun # <------
    def run(self, times):
        for i in xrange(times):
            print "%s. run... %s" % (i, self.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it be a class but you need to use the descriptor protocol

```
 import types

 class canRun(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.o = object  # <-- What the hell is this about? 

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if self.longcondition():
            self.f(*args)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
         return types.MethodType(self, instance)
```

You always need to use a descriptor when you want to decorate class methods with a class instance using the `__call__` method. The reason for this is that there will only be one `self` passed in which refers to the instance of the decorating class and not the instance of the decorated method.

Answer (score 5):

There's no real need to implement this decorator as a class, and there's no need to implement it inside the definition of the `Foo` class.  The following will suffice:

```
def canRun(meth):
    def decorated_meth(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.longcondition():
            print 'Can run'
            return meth(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print 'Cannot run'
            return None
    return decorated_meth
```

Using that decorator seems to work:

```
>>> Foo('hello').run(5)
Can run
0. run... hello
1. run... hello
2. run... hello
3. run... hello
4. run... hello
>>> Foo(123).run(5)
Cannot run
```

Comment: Note that this implementation assumes that it will be decorating bound methods, and so could not be used to decorate arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was made in haste. If you're wanting to write a decorator you should really use `wraps` from the `functools` module. It takes care of the hard stuff for you.

A proper way to define the canRun decorator is:

```
from functools import wraps
def canRun(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def wrapper(instance, *args):
    if instance.longcondition():
      return f(instance, *args)
  return wrapper
```

The canRun function should be defined outside of the class.

Comment: this doesn't work and there is no reason to expect that it should. You want a descriptor. See my answer.

Comment: @aaronasterling, you're absolutely right. I based my answer on previous experience using functools.wraps without testing to see if it worked. I've updated my answer to use it